# spark application does not stop when multiple threads share the same spark context

Tags: java, apache-spark

I have tried to reproduce the problem i am facing. My problem statement - In a folder multiple files are present. I need to do word counts for each file and print the result. Each file should be processed parallely! of course, there is a limit to parallelism. I have written the following code to accomplish it. It is running fine.The cluster is having spark installation of mapR. The cluster has spark.scheduler.mode = FIFO.

> Q1- is there a better  way to accomplish the task mentioned above?
>
> Q2- i have observed that the application does not stop even when it
>   has completed the word counting of avaialble files. i am unable to
>   figure out how to deal with it?

```
package groupId.artifactId;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;

public class Executor {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        final int threadPoolSize = 5;       
        SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-client").setAppName("Tracker").set("spark.ui.port","0");
        JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf); 
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
        List<Future> listOfFuture = new ArrayList<Future>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            if (listOfFuture.size() < threadPoolSize) {
                FlexiWordCount flexiWordCount = new FlexiWordCount(jsc, i);
                Future future = executor.submit(flexiWordCount);
                listOfFuture.add(future);               
            } else {
                boolean allFutureDone = false;
                while (!allFutureDone) {
                    allFutureDone = checkForAllFuture(listOfFuture);
                    System.out.println("Threads not completed yet!");
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(2000);//waiting for 2 sec, before next check
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                printFutureResult(listOfFuture);
                System.out.println("printing of future done");
                listOfFuture.clear();
                System.out.println("future list got cleared");
            }

        }
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }



    private static void printFutureResult(List<Future> listOfFuture) {
        Iterator<Future> iterateFuture = listOfFuture.iterator();
        while (iterateFuture.hasNext()) {
            Future tempFuture = iterateFuture.next();
            try {
                System.out.println("Future result " + tempFuture.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private static boolean checkForAllFuture(List<Future> listOfFuture) {
        boolean status = true;
        Iterator<Future> iterateFuture = listOfFuture.iterator();
        while (iterateFuture.hasNext()) {
            Future tempFuture = iterateFuture.next();
            if (!tempFuture.isDone()) {
                status = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        return status;
```

### }

```
package groupId.artifactId;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaPairRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.FlatMapFunction;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.Function2;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.PairFunction;

import scala.Tuple2;

public class FlexiWordCount implements Callable<Object>,Serializable {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JavaSparkContext jsc;
    private int fileId;

    public FlexiWordCount(JavaSparkContext jsc, int fileId) {
        super();
        this.jsc = jsc;
        this.fileId = fileId;
    }
    private static class Reduction implements Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>{
        @Override
        public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
            return i1 + i2;
        }
    }

    private static class KVPair implements PairFunction<String, String, Integer>{
        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String paramT)
                throws Exception {
            return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(paramT, 1);
        }
    }
    private static class Flatter implements FlatMapFunction<String, String>{

        @Override
        public Iterable<String> call(String s) {
            return Arrays.asList(s.split(" "));
        }
    }
    @Override
    public Object call() throws Exception { 
        JavaRDD<String> jrd = jsc.textFile("/root/folder/experiment979/" + fileId +".txt");
        System.out.println("inside call() for fileId = " + fileId);
        JavaRDD<String> words = jrd.flatMap(new Flatter());
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> ones = words.mapToPair(new KVPair());      
        JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = ones.reduceByKey(new Reduction());
        return counts.collect();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why is Program not closing automatically ?

Ans :  you have not closed the Sparkcontex , try changing main method to this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    final int threadPoolSize = 5;       
    SparkConf sparkConf = new SparkConf().setMaster("yarn-client").setAppName("Tracker").set("spark.ui.port","0");
    JavaSparkContext jsc = new JavaSparkContext(sparkConf); 
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
    List<Future> listOfFuture = new ArrayList<Future>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        if (listOfFuture.size() < threadPoolSize) {
            FlexiWordCount flexiWordCount = new FlexiWordCount(jsc, i);
            Future future = executor.submit(flexiWordCount);
            listOfFuture.add(future);               
        } else {
            boolean allFutureDone = false;
            while (!allFutureDone) {
                allFutureDone = checkForAllFuture(listOfFuture);
                System.out.println("Threads not completed yet!");
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(2000);//waiting for 2 sec, before next check
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            printFutureResult(listOfFuture);
            System.out.println("printing of future done");
            listOfFuture.clear();
            System.out.println("future list got cleared");
        }

    }
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   jsc.stop()
    }
```

Is there a better way ?

Ans : Yes you should pass the directory of the files to sparkcontext and use .textFile over directory , in this case spark would parallaize the reads from directories over the executors . If you try to create threads yourself and then use the same spark context to re-submit job for each file you are adding a extra overhead of submitting application to yarn queue .

I think the fastest approach would be to directly pass the entire directory and create RDD out of it and then then let spark launch parallel task to process all the files in different executors .You can experiment with using .repartition() method over the RDD , as it would launch that many tasks to run parallely .

Comment: Actually, I have tried to reproduce the problem, by giving example of word count. What i mean to say is , whatever the processing logic is , that needs to be applied on different datasets. so, to achieve performance, we tried using different threads. Also, i cant close the spark context because it will be shared by different threads as shown here. well, suppose it is a server program that keeps spawning threads and after they are complete, spawn next set of threads.